# Spring boot and Akka cluster actor dependency injection not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, akka, akka-cluster

I am trying to use Spring boot and akka. I have two processes and communicate with akka cluster. Only process A uses spring boot.

```
@Autowired
private ActorSystem springActorSystem;

@Autowired
private SpringExtension springExtension;

private ActorRef caActor;
caActor = springActorSystem.actorOf(springExtension.props("clientAgentActor"), "ca");
```

If I create the actor on process A, of course, using springExtension, all injections are working. However, the caActor is a cluster actor. If process B send a message to process A, the ClientAgentActor invoked somewhere, all injections are failed.
How to solve it?

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class ClientAgentActor extends AbstractActor {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ClientAgentActor.class);

@Autowired
ClientAgentService caService;

@Autowired
LineService lineService;

@Override
public Receive createReceive() {
    //TODO
    return receiveBuilder().match(String.class, msg -> logger.debug(msg)).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought the same for almost whole day. And I think there is no way to integrate Spring into Akka cluster with full DI for cross-cluster calls without changing the core of Akka Cluster.

When you do call without cluster inside one JVM you use Akka wrapper instead of pure Akka. 
But when you do call in cluster this call is recieved on other node by pure Akka infrastructure without Spring wrapper, so this infrastructure doesn't know about Spring actors proxies that's why you see no injections.

So if you need Spring in Akka Cluster you need to wrap the core of this library with Spring infrastructure. Except it would be not easy to implement it would be also hard to follow the Akka rules and conventions in application architecture. For example, it would be too easy to inject transitive dependency which has blocking calls or multithreading code.

If you need to use some Spring functionality I think the best way to do this is to fully separate Akka infrastructure from Spring's one. And after application initialization set global static field with created ApplicationContext and make applicationContext.getBean(...) calls where they are needed. Of course you can do comfortable method for this. Or for example class with public static fields with needed beans which are set once after Spring initialization completes.